Saxon XSLT | Sum Function
Perhaps this was already asked but I haven't been able to locate any posts on this. We use Saxon (HE-9.5.1-2) and the function sum returns a rather unusual value. Sum of 196.30 and 1018.57 is 1214.87 while Saxon returns a value of 1214.8700000000001.
Here's the repro.
Any inputs are appreciated. Thanks.

The behavior you observe has nothing to do with Saxon or XSLT; it has to do with how floating point numbers are represented in computers in general.   See What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic [classic paper] or Is computer math broken? [explanatory video].

Use the xs:decimal data type
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(item/xs:decimal(.))"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

and you will get e.g. <root>1214.87</root>.
The default number type is IEEE double (xs:double), the same as for instance the number type in JavaScript and for that you will find the same floating point imprecision:


var n1 = 196.30;
var n2 = 1018.57;

var sum = n1 + n2;

console.log(sum);



And of course it is not Saxon specific, any compliant XSLT processor for your code will use double number precision and should give that result.

thanks, the behaviour apparently is not generic. For example, decimals 289.05 and 1640.91 produces an expected output of 1929.96. Is applying format-number(sum(item), '.##') an acceptable alternative?

You will need to dig up the IEEE double standard to understand for which representations you get imprecisions, I would strongly suggest that in the context of XSLT 2 or later using xs:decimal is the way to go for any numerical computations; of course in the context of number outputting and/or XSLT 1.0 you can use format-number to cut off the decimals you consider incorrect/unwanted.
